# многопоточность для цикла

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, opencv

У меня есть 2 функции обнаруживающие сцены из двух разных видеоисточников. Первый источник - непрерывный стрим веб-камеры, а второй - видеофайл. Также я использую for-loop в которой происходит обработка обнаруженных кадров этих 2 видео. Я пытаюсь использовать многопоточность, но программа не доходит до `for-loop`’а. Подскажите пожалуйста, что я не так делаю. Вот отрывок кода:

```
def callback_1(image, frame_num):
  global scenes_1
  print("callback_1: Found a scene on video 1.")
  scenes_1 += [(image, frame_num)]
  
def callback_2(image, frame_num):
  global scenes_2
  print("callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.")
  scenes_2 += [(image, frame_num)]
  
def function_1():
  cap = BrowserVideoCapture(src=0)
  scene_manager1.detect_scenes(cap, callback=callback_1)

def function_2():
  cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture("Our Story.mp4")
  scene_manager2.detect_scenes(cap2, callback=callback_2)

t1=threading.Thread(target=function_1)
t2=threading.Thread(target=function_2)

t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
  
for (im2, frame_num2), (im1, frame_num1) in zip(scenes_2, scenes_1):
  tar_image_example = cv2.cvtColor(im2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
  tar_image_example = tar_image_example.astype(np.uint8)
  print("Found scene at frame %d in video 2." % frame_num2)
  src_image_example = cv2.cvtColor(im1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
  src_image_example = src_image_example.astype(np.uint8)
  print("Found scene at frame %d in video 1." % frame_num1)
```

Ниже вывод программы:

```
16%|█▌        | 360/2321 [00:00<00:03, 490.74frames/s]callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
 27%|██▋       | 629/2321 [00:00<00:02, 714.27frames/s]callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
 38%|███▊      | 881/2321 [00:00<00:01, 893.42frames/s]callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
 51%|█████▏    | 1192/2321 [00:01<00:00, 1142.96frames/s]callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
 71%|███████   | 1644/2321 [00:01<00:00, 1355.45frames/s]callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
 84%|████████▍ | 1952/2321 [00:01<00:00, 1440.39frames/s]callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
100%|██████████| 2321/2321 [00:01<00:00, 1323.65frames/s]callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
callback_2: Found a scene on video 2.
 16%|█▌        | 16/100 [00:17<01:27,  1.04s/frames]callback_1: Found a scene on video 1.
 43%|████▎     | 43/100 [00:45<00:55,  1.03frames/s]callback_1: Found a scene on video 1.
 79%|███████▉  | 79/100 [01:21<00:21,  1.01s/frames]callback_1: Found a scene on video 1.
110frames [01:52,  1.00s/frames]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-7b352782e239> in <module>()
     54 t1.start()
     55 t2.start()
---> 56 t1.join()
     57 t2.join()
     58 

1 frames
/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py in join(self, timeout)
   1042 
   1043         if timeout is None:
-> 1044             self._wait_for_tstate_lock()
   1045         else:
   1046             # the behavior of a negative timeout isn't documented, but

/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py in _wait_for_tstate_lock(self, block, timeout)
   1058         if lock is None:  # already determined that the C code is done
   1059             assert self._is_stopped
-> 1060         elif lock.acquire(block, timeout):
   1061             lock.release()
   1062             self._stop()

KeyboardInterrupt:
```

Как видите код отрабатывает только часть поверх `for-loop` зависая на стриме с веб-камеры

Comment: А без отдельного потока `function_1` просто сама по себе (без `function_2`) нормально работает, пробовали? У меня подозрение, что то, что там происходит, может работать только в основном потоке, поскольку оно взаимодействует с `GUI`. А если попробовать запустить `function_2` в потоке, а следом `function_1` просто так, без отдельного потока?

Comment: @Roman Konoval Спасибо большое, выручили!

Answer (score 1):

В [документации](https://pyscenedetect.readthedocs.io/projects/Manual/en/latest/api/scene_manager.html) к detect_scenes написано:

> Blocks until all frames in the frame_source have been processed.

Похоже что `BrowserVideoCapture` дает непрерывный поток, в котором просто кадры не кончаются. Вероятно, в `detect_scenes` нужно передавать параметр `end_time`, чтоб ограничить количество обрабатываемого видео.